# Angular 4 unit testing mock backend creates undefined answer

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am trying to test this service with Angular tests

```
export class LoginService implements OnInit {
  private authUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/login';
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {

      let _sub = this.http.post(this.authUrl, JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}))
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let token = response.json()['Token'];
        let role = response.json()['Role'];
        if (token) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({username: username, token: token, role: role}));
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }).catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
      return _sub;
  }
  getToken(): String {
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    let token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
    return token ? token : '';
  }
  logout(): void {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }
  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    let token: String = this.getToken();
    return token && token.length > 0;
  }
```

i have created a mockbackend response that should be a json but the response is undefined

```
describe('LoginService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
      MockBackend,
      BaseRequestOptions,
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
        LoginService,
      ]
    });
  });


  it('should set the token,user and role', inject([LoginService,XHRBackend], (service,mockBackend)=>{

        const mockResponse= {
            role:'mockRole',
            user:'mockUser',
            token:'mockToken'
        };
        mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection)=>{
                 connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
                       status:200,
                       body:JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
                 })));
        }); 
        console.log(mockBackend);
        service.login('mockuser','mockpassword').subscribe((response)=>
          {console.log(response.json);}
        );
        expect(service.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(true);
  }));
```

As far as i can tell from logs the mockbackend is correctly injected in the login service and the response gets registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `login` method places a `map` operator that changes the response for a `boolean`, the only thing you'll be able to get from `login()` observable is `true` or `false`.

That being said, `boolean.json` can't be a property, so you get `undefined`, try to `console.log(response)` instead of `console.log(response.json)` and you'll probably have either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you!It is now working also there was a problem because in my mockResponse i had 'token' instead of 'Token' but now everything works.

Comment: @titusbocioc don't forget to check the accepted answer to mark the question revoled and avoid other people to come here to help you and find this comment that says 'the problem is resolved'.